# How to boot into Linux/Ubuntu emergency mode with read only option, when default behavior ignores "ro" flag?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to repair the root partition in an Ubuntu 20.04 server. However, I cannot manage to boot the server into rescue or emergency mode ***and*** have the root partition *read-only* to be able to run the checks.

My Grub2 boot menu Linux command line looks like the following

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-... root=/dev/mapper/vgname-lvname ro emergency
```

I also have tried the `systemd.unit=emergency.target` approach, but this also didn't work.

The console greets me with the correct line:

> You are in emergency mode.
> [...]
> Give root password for maintenance
> (or press Control-D to continue):

However, entering the root password and checking the root mount point reveals that root is mounted read-write instead of read-only.

```
/dev/mapper/vgname-lvname on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

`mount -o remount,ro /` (or the LVM volume) fails due to the mount point is busy.

How to force read-only mode in the emergency mode?